# Launching urxvt with calendar (cal) using sxhkd

Tags: rxvt, calendar, cal, sxhkd

Hi I'm trying to launch cal with sxhkd. And it doesn't work, the terminal window is closed right after the command is executed.

I tried to do it using the following:

```
# launch urxvt 20x8 with cal
super + c
    urxvt -geometry 20x8 -e cal -m
```

I also tried to set bspwm to open the window as floating with this: `bspc rule -a urxvt:cal state:floating` but it doesn't have any efect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-hold` on urxvt, in order to not destroy its window when the program executed within it exits.

```
urxvt -hold -geometry 20x8 -e cal -m
```